# Using regular expression in R to grep strings inside similar strings

Tags: r, regex

I have a vector full of links to csv and zip addresses (besides text), but I only want to extract the addresses containing zip files.

But sometimes the address for the zip and csv are on the same line like:

> http:/something.csv  http:/something.zip

How can I use regex in R to pick only the zip link?  For instance,

> http:/..something.zip

I tried the pattern `http(.*?)zip`, it doesn't work because it returns the whole sentence since the whole sentence begins with "http".

Comment: http\\S*?zip  should work  (Notice that is a capital S)

Comment: What about `links[grep(pattern = ".zip$",x = links)]`?

Comment: I don't think that solves :(. regmatches(vector,regexpr("http[^\\s]*?zip",vector))character(0) where "vector" is the sentence with the links. And sometimes there is no blank space but lots of text between the csv and zip links

Comment: No blanks, huh?  OK.  Could you show us a few lines so that we can see what your data look like?

Comment: Now I saw the edited comment #G5W thanks! Does it work because there is no blank space in the zip link itself?

Comment: Also, you wrote `regmatches(vector,regexpr("http[^\\s]*?zip",vector))`  shouldn't that just be `regmatches(vector,regexpr("http[^\\s]*?zip"))`

Comment: The "http\\S*?zip" did the job thanks! I'm new to stackoverflow sorry about the comments. The regexpr command seems to require both the pattern and the original vector ...else it returns an error

Answer (score 1):

It should work with just the following:

```
links[grep(".zip", links)]
```

Comment: This will not work since I want to extract the link, not only see if it is in the vector (which I already know). Thanks for trying to help though...the @G5W answer did the job...